# What software can I use to make handwritten notes, do handwritten math or science on my macOS10.13?

Tags: note-taking, macos, math, drawing, writing

What software can I use to make handwritten notes, do handwritten math or science on my macOS10.13?

I need a canvas so I can do all my math, like how it is done in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r5TtnjRzaY.

Is there a lightweight, preferably open-source software for this? (preferably not photoshop.)

Also, I tried microPad, but when I tried to write with my finger on my Macbook (A1990, 15-inch, year 2018), it was very difficult to write. Is this a software or hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

Xournal++ is open source and also has [a macOS build](https://xournalpp.github.io/installation/macos/), if 10.13.x/High Sierra is too old, you could try to upgrade (according to everymac.com A1990 supports up to current macOS).

Regarding the writing, usually notes like these are made using a drawing tablet, as it's not an artistic drawing even a cheap one should be enough.